# IPC on Terminal Server with C/C++ an nw.js/node.js/node-native-module (C++)?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, ipc, nw.js

I have a Win32-DLL (C++) which is loaded as a plugin in another application. The DLL starts a nw.js instance (ShellExecuteEx and SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS) and ends it at DLL unloading (by the hInstance of ShellExecuteEx). I need a way to send a string (plain ansi) to the nw-process and retrieve an answer (also string). The old way was a simple http-request with the response in the body. But the environment changes during the development, the "package" app-dll-nw runs multiple times by the same user and multiple users run on the same machine (terminal server). So port listing is "impossible" (yeah random ports or singleton nw, but no).

I found different ways:

- socket - port listing problem
- wm_copydata/wm_... - need a custom nw-plugin with hidden window (no native nw way); no request-response-system
- RPC - port listing problem
- DDE - no native javascript way (found a module, which uses .net); In my old delphi days DDE was a not so simple task and it failed multiple times with no logic.
- shared memory - no experience; expectations: asynchronous, trigger?, no native javascript way
- shared file - no experience; expectations: asynchronous, trigger (watcher on file change) but problems with synchronization, native js way possible
- named pipe - no experience; expectations: win32-api and like a chat system (in-pipe [send broadcast] and out-pipe [receive broadcast], or both in one)? If yes, I can use one name about all instances and use unique identifiers and wait for the right answer.

What is a nice and simple way to communicate like the http-way but w/o networking?

**Update 1**: The node module "net" is able to create a server for a named pipe. The first test, sending a string from the dll to nw, was successful.

```
var server = net.createServer(function(stream) {
      stream.on('data', function(c) {
        console.log('data:', c.toString());
      });
      stream.on('end', function() {
        //server.close();
      });
    });
    server.listen('\\\\.\\pipe\\MyAppDynamicGUID');
```

**Update 2 - My Solution**

With named pipe and a simplified version of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592(v=vs.85).aspx I found a working methode.

Server in nw.js:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(req) {
    req.on('data', function(c) {
        console.log(c.toString());
        req.write('123|Hello World', 'ascii');
    });
});
server.listen('\\\\.\\pipe\\MyAppDynamicGUID');
```

The client in C++ (no permanent connection, strange string handling, simplified error handling):

```
static std::string PipenameA = "\\\\.\\pipe\\MyAppDynamicGUID";
#define BUFSIZE 512
std::string SendPipeRequestA(std::string sRequest) {
    DWORD dwToWrite, dwWritten, dwRead;
    BOOL bSuccess;
    char chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateFileA(PipenameA.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return "-1|Pipe-Error 1 (connect)";
    dwToWrite = (lstrlenA(sRequest.c_str())+1)*sizeof(char);
    bSuccess = WriteFile(hPipe, sRequest.c_str(), dwToWrite, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess)
        return "-1|Pipe-Error 2 (write)";
    do { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe, chBuf, BUFSIZE*sizeof(char), &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            break;
        buffer.insert(buffer.end(), chBuf, chBuf + dwRead);
    } while (!bSuccess);
    std::string sResponse(&buffer[0]);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
    return sResponse.c_str();
}
```

// Jonny

Answer (score 0):

The answers you will get will be opinion based, be aware of that.

you can inject the data into the JS module as command line argument
for example
`start nw.js MyData`
and get it insinde the JS with `process.argv`.

now, sending the data back to the C++ executables/DLLs is a bit tricky.
if you shell-execute the process, you can have the handle to it.
you can print the data into the stdout from the JS part , and read it in the native app by getting the STDOUT handle from the process handle.

Comment: The problem is not the start arguments. I need a permanent possibility to send messages. The stdin and stdout was also an idea, but the nw has no native posibility to write in stdXY. Also, I am not sure, if the reading and writing to the std is to complicated for the dll, because this part need an extra thread. The dll waits for calls of the main application, and a waiting on the std blocks the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

Register your nw.js app with a custom url should be an elegant way.
Such as "github://", "thunder://", "twitter://"

On windows you may have a look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

With custom url you can take simple arguments to nw.js at single-instance mode. See:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Handling-files-and-arguments#open-file-with-existing-app

If more data required maybe base64 can help, or even more by LZ-String compress method.